# Cannot define absolute path in maven plugin

Tags: java, maven

I added the surefire plugin to maven, and need to add jars to the classpath for the tests to work. If the jar is in the same directory as pom.xml, it works fine:

```
    <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.0-M5</version>
        <configuration>
            <additionalClasspathElements>
                <additionalClasspathElement>jooq-3.11.10.jar</additionalClasspathElement>
                </additionalClasspathElements>
        </configuration>
    </plugin>
```

But if I define the absolute path, it doesn't find it. I need to point the jar to the location where it is. Why does this happen and how to make this work?

```
    <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.0-M5</version>
        <configuration>
            <additionalClasspathElements>

                // doesn't find this jar
                <additionalClasspathElement>c:\my\path\jooq-3.11.10.jar</additionalClasspathElement>

            </additionalClasspathElements>
        </configuration>
    </plugin>
```

Comment: have you tried this c:\\my\\path\\jooq-3.11.10.jar

Comment: yes, I tried that and it didn't work

Comment: this worked, a relative path: `<additionalClasspathElement>\path\jooq-3.11.10.jar</additionalClasspathElement>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest to use test scope dependencies like the following:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.jooq</groupId>
  <artifactId>jooq</artifactId>
  <version>3.11.10</version>
  <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

That will add the dependency automatically on the classpath for testing only. There is no need to add things like that manually with path in maven-surefire-plugin.

Comment: This worked, however I had to add `javax.transaction` to `pom.xml` and I don't know if this would cause a conflict with WildFly.

Comment: You might need to define the scope for that as `<scope>provided</scope>` if it's already in WildFly...